# hadoop - datanode decommission

Tags: java, cluster, hadoop

I want to remove nodes from my cluster **gracefully**. I added the following to my hadoop-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.hosts.exclude</name>
  <value>/etc/hadoop/conf.dist/dfs.hosts.exclude</value>
  <final>true</final>
</property>
```

I'm adding a node to be removed to the file and executing

> ```
> hadoop dfsadmin -refreshNodes
> ```

as root, but I get

> ```
> refreshNodes: org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.AccessControlException: Superuser privilege is required
> ```

The mod on the HDFS partition is 777.

Running Cloudera's hadoop-ec2 distribution, ver 0.18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look in ${HADOOP_CONF_DIR}/hadoop-policy.xml and see if the root has permissions to do that, root maybe superuser over the system, however may not be over the app.

Try thi link http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/service_level_auth.html

Stuart

Answer (score 0):

The property dfs.hosts.exclude names a file that contains a list of hosts that are not permitted to connect to the namenode.  The full pathname of the file must be specified.

`cd <hadoop_installation>/bin`

- To start datanode

`hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode`

- To start tasktracker

`hadoop-daemon.sh start tasktracker`

- To stop datanode (remove the datanode from the cluster)

`hadoop-daemon.sh stop datanode`

- To stop tasktracker (remove tasktracker from the cluster)

`hadoop-daemon.sh stop tasktracker`